# How to represent a sum of dirac delta function and a linear function in a graph? (convention question)

Tags: signal, signal-processing, graph

I'm working on my final assignment in signal's course that I'm taking. I want to represent the following function in a graph:

\$ f(t)=\delta\left(t+1\right)+(t+1.5) \$

Where \$ -1.5<t<0 \$.

Generally we represent dirac-delta function as the following:

[image]

And the other function that I want to sum looks like this:

[image]

So how the summation of the graph's should be ? should it be like this:

[image]

Or maybe like this: ?

[image]

Or maybe a totally different way?

Thanks in advance, this is highly appreciated and extremely important for me.

Comment: It's the last picture. Don't forget that Dirac is [weird](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4063279/334505) (link to math.se).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen So you do not agree with the answer I got here?

Comment: What aswer? You're just showing 2 signals & 2 options. Out of the 4 pictures, the 4th is the one I would choose. But, as you can [see](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/554848/95619), there are other views, mostly because of [KD9PDP's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554844/how-to-represent-a-sum-of-dirac-delta-function-and-a-linear-function-in-a-graph?noredirect=1#comment1447022_554848) -- which would nullify both Enrico's answer and my option, because Dirac is a concept, and distributions or whatever else are only attempts at a mathematical representation.

Answer (score 2):

The third graph is correct.

The fourth graph is wrong because Dirac's delta functions (they are actually math functionals) can't be summed to ordinary functions.

Comment: I agree with this one - when you "add" a dirac delta to something, it's kind of magic at that point - plotting it is kind of weird. So, in a way, there isn't a convention because you don't really plot it often (ever). In complex analysis you just mark it as a pole on the complex plane, or as a pole on the projection on an axis.

Comment: The Dirac's delta is more precisely a "functional".

Answer (score 1):

Dirac-delta function has the following definition:

$$\delta(t) = \{ ^{\infty,t=0}_{0,t\ne0}  $$

so by definition, your function will be :

$$f(t)=  \delta(t+1)+(t+1.5) = \begin{cases}\infty, &\text{for }t=-1 \\ t+1.5,& \text{for } 
t \ne -1\end{cases}$$

This is the actual definition of the function. Although I don't know what the straight vertical arrow represents in the above graphs but I assuming that it represents a point which is at infinity, therefore, by this logic, your last and last second graph are not different at all.

Let me explain myself a little more. If you draw a vertical arrow just to represent some point which is at infinity, then even by shifting that arrow vertically won't change the fact that it is representing a point at infinity. Remember this, There is only one true definition of your function and no matter how you draw your graph, it should conform to its definition. So, you see no matter if you draw your graph either way, they both conform to the function's definition.